# React Simple Unit Test for Reducer

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I am trying to do a simple unit test for a reducer in react.js.
I passed undefined as the initial state and an empty action as the second parameter in the test for the reducer. I expected the test to pass but i get an error as shown below. This complaining about what i am passing into the reducer.Can anyone tell me how to overcome this. Thanks

```
TypeError: (0 , _Global2.default) is not a function
      at Object.it (src/__tests__/Global.test.js:5:33)
          at new Promise (<anonymous>)
      at Promise.resolve.then.el (node_modules/p-map/index.js:46:16)
```

Heres my Global state with the reducer

```
const loginVisibility = Object.freeze({
    Visible: 'VISIBLE',
    Hidden: 'HIDDEN'
});
const initialState = { show: false };

export const actionCreators = {
  hideLogin: () => ({ 
    type: loginVisibility.Hidden,
  }),
  showLogin: () => ({ 
    type: loginVisibility.Visible,
  }),
};

export const reducer = (state, action) => {
  state = state || initialState;

  if (action.type === loginVisibility.Visible) {
    return { ...state, show: true };
  }

  if (action.type === loginVisibility.Hidden) {
    return { ...state, show: false };
  }

  return state;
};
```

And here is my Global.test.js file

```
import reducer from '../store/state/Global';

describe('Login Visibility',()=>{
 it('Should return the initial state',()=>{
   expect(reducer(undefined,{})).toEqual({
      show: false
   })
 })
});
```

Answer (score 2):

This is how you should import your reducer:

```
import { reducer } from '../store/state/Global';
```

Because in your reducer you are using **named** exports